# Нарастающий итог с группировкой и фильтрацией, без под-селекта и без вендоро-зависимых расширений

Tags: sql

То, чего я добиваюсь: нарастающий итог по quantity и amount с начала дня, за нужную дату, с разбивкой по hour.

Знаю, что в Oracle и MSSQL есть специальные операторы для получения таких данных и что в Postgres есть SELECT OVER PARTITION.
Но сейчас (прототип) используется MySQL (или MariaDB, Percona и т.п.), что будет в продакшне - не знаю. Поэтому нельзя отклоняться в вендоро-зависимые расширения.

Вся таблица:

```
> SELECT id, dir, product, date, hour, quantity, amount FROM sales order by date, hour;

+------+-----+---------+------------+------+----------+--------+
| id   | dir | product | date       | hour | quantity | amount |
+------+-----+---------+------------+------+----------+--------+
| 2230 |  65 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-11 |    1 |        1 |     10 |
| 2231 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-11 |    3 |        4 |     40 |
| 2232 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-11 |    5 |        5 |     50 |
| 2235 |  64 | ZZ      | 2014-09-11 |    7 |        6 |     60 |
| 2233 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-11 |    7 |        6 |     60 |
| 2237 |  66 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-11 |    7 |        6 |     60 |
| 2234 |  64 | ZZ      | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 |
| 2236 |  66 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
| 2227 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
| 2228 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    5 |        2 |    200 |
| 2229 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    7 |        3 |    300 |
+------+-----+---------+------------+------+----------+--------+
```

За нужную дату:

```
> SELECT id, dir, product, date, hour, quantity, amount FROM sales WHERE date = '2014-09-18';

+------+-----+---------+------------+------+----------+--------+
| id   | dir | product | date       | hour | quantity | amount |
+------+-----+---------+------------+------+----------+--------+
| 2227 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
| 2228 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    5 |        2 |    200 |
| 2229 |  64 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    7 |        3 |    300 |
| 2234 |  64 | ZZ      | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 |
| 2236 |  66 | ABCDEDF | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
+------+-----+---------+------------+------+----------+--------+
```

То, чего я добиваюсь, под-селектом. Результат, как надо.

```
> SELECT date, hour, SUM(quantity),
  ( SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM sales s2
    WHERE s2.hour <= s1.hour AND s2.date = s1.date
  ) AS total
  FROM sales s1
  WHERE s1.date = '2014-09-18'
  GROUP by date, hour;

+------------+------+---------------+-------+
| date       | hour | sum(quantity) | total |
+------------+------+---------------+-------+
| 2014-09-18 |    3 |             3 |     3 |
| 2014-09-18 |    5 |             2 |     5 |
| 2014-09-18 |    7 |             3 |     8 |
+------------+------+---------------+-------+
```

Смущает:

1. Если записей в таблице будет много (а их будет около миллиона), то подзапросы будут выполнятся в огромном количестве.
2. Если мне нужно делать выборку только по какому-то продукту или по дирекции, мне нужно эти условия прописывать и в запрос и в подзапрос (`WHERE product =` / `WHERE dir =`).
3. Считает только одну сумму, а мне нужно две (`sum(quantity)` и `sum(amount)`) (`ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`).

Ближайший результат с JOIN'ом:

```
> SELECT DISTINCT(s1.hour) AS ih, s2.date, s2.hour, s2.quantity, s2.amount, s2.id FROM sales s1 JOIN sales s2 ON s2.date = s1.date AND s2.hour <= s1.hour WHERE s1.date = '2014-09-18' ORDER by ih;

+----+------------+------+----------+--------+------+
| ih | date       | hour | quantity | amount | id   |
+----+------------+------+----------+--------+------+
|  3 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 | 2236 |
|  3 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 | 2227 |
|  3 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 | 2234 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 | 2236 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 | 2227 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    5 |        2 |    200 | 2228 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 | 2234 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 | 2236 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 | 2227 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    5 |        2 |    200 | 2228 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    7 |        3 |    300 | 2229 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 | 2234 |
+----+------------+------+----------+--------+------+
```

В варианте без DISTINCT строки имеют дубли. Вариации JOIN'ов не помогают.

Как только убираю s2.id из SELECT, получается ерунда, значимые строки просто пропадают:

```
> SELECT DISTINCT(s1.hour) AS ih, s2.date, s2.hour, s2.quantity, s2.amount FROM sales s1 JOIN sales s2 ON s2.date = s1.date AND s2.hour <= s1.hour WHERE s1.date = '2014-09-18' ORDER by ih;

+----+------------+------+----------+--------+
| ih | date       | hour | quantity | amount |
+----+------------+------+----------+--------+
|  3 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
|  3 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    5 |        2 |    200 |
|  5 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |    100 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    5 |        2 |    200 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    7 |        3 |    300 |
|  7 | 2014-09-18 |    3 |        1 |     11 |
+----+------------+------+----------+--------+
```

Суммирование не помогает, наоборот, добавляет ещё проблем.
В строках, соответствующих ih = 3 сумма по s2.quantity 9, а должна быть 3. Сумма по s1.quantity вообще непонятно из чего состоит.

```
> SELECT DISTINCT(s1.hour) AS ih, sum(s1.quantity), s2.date, SUM(s2.quantity) FROM sales s1 JOIN sales s2 ON s2.date = s1.date AND s2.hour <= s1.hour WHERE s1.date = '2014-09-18' GROUP BY ih;

+----+------------------+------------+------------------+
| ih | sum(s1.quantity) | date       | sum(s2.quantity) |
+----+------------------+------------+------------------+
|  3 |                9 | 2014-09-18 |                9 |
|  5 |                8 | 2014-09-18 |                5 |
|  7 |               15 | 2014-09-18 |                8 |
+----+------------------+------------+------------------+
```

Бонус очки:
  Нужна ещё колонка total_reference, в которой будет указан нарастающий итог для того же периода (с начала дня по hour), но для другой даты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, нужно просто привести набор к один час => одна запись. И для каждой записи из такого набора вычислять нарастающий итог:

```
SELECT s1.date, s1.hour, s1.quantity, sum(s2.quantity) as total
FROM (select date, hour, sum(quantity) as quantity
      from sales group by date, hour) s1 
  JOIN sales s2 ON 
    s2.date = s1.date AND s2.hour <= s1.hour
WHERE s1.date = '2014-09-18' 
group by s1.date, s1.hour
ORDER by s1.date, s1.hour;
```

Чтоб получить бонус за другую дату, надо обернуть этот запрос (сделать его вложенным) и добавить агрегацию по записям аналогично:

```
select s1.date, s1.hour, s1.quantity, s1.total, sum(ifnull(s2.quantity,0)) as total_reference
from (
  SELECT s11.date, s11.hour, s11.quantity, sum(s12.quantity) as total
    FROM (select date, hour, sum(quantity) as quantity
      from sales group by date, hour) s11 
    JOIN sales s12 ON 
      s12.date = s11.date AND s12.hour <= s11.hour
    WHERE s11.date = '2014-09-18' 
    group by s11.date, s11.hour) s1 
  left join sales s2 on 
    s1.date = date_add(s2.date, interval 7 day) and s2.hour <= s1.hour
group by s1.date, s1.hour, s1.quantity, s1.total
ORDER by s1.date, s1.hour;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e46008/1)

Comment: Ещё оказались нужны за предыдущую дату не только данные нарастающим итогом, но и просто сумма за час, и добавилась вложенность SELECT, итого 4. Это точно будет нормально работать с миллионом записей в исходной таблице (учитывая то, что за два дня записей будет не так много, порядка пары тысяч)? Не стоит ли на самый внутренний SELECT (s11) наложить фильтр по вхождению дат в список из интересующих двух?

Comment: Да, разумеется. Чем меньше записей будет на каждом этапе (каждый вложенный запрос возвращать), тем быстрее все будет работать, поэтому фильтры во внутренних запросах помогут.    
По поводу количества запросов. Ну да, скорость расти не будет, понятное дело. Но смысл тут в том, что фактически запросов будет 4, а не N по количеству записей, как в случае с зависимым запросом. Погоняйте на реальном объеме, добавьте индексов (например, составной на дату+час), думаю, будет приемлемо...